# Geometry/Geography type issue for US Census TIGER ShapeFiles

Tags: shapefile, sql-server, fiona, tiger, geopandas

I'm loading the ShapeFiles from TIGER into SQL Server (via Python Geopandas/Fiona). It seems the boundaries are all of the Geometry data type (flat-earth).

Do these file exist in the Geography format (round-earth, lat/long)?

Here's a link to the FTP site: ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2017/

And the web interface:https://www.census.gov/cgi-bin/geo/shapefiles/index.php